# Discord bot deleting message after sending

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a filter on my discord bot that deletes messages from everyone that include "discord.gg, @everyone, @here" unless they have an admin role. My filter checks for every message sent, it first checks if that user has the admin role then checks the contents. If someone sends a message(with one or all of those 3 blacklisted words) while having the admin role, the bot will allow the message to be sent.
Somehow the filter stopped working and I have no clue. The bot is written in discord.py.
The problem is that the filter stops the bot from sending any kind of message. I have narrowed to line 2(from this chunk of code).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '735893522032623646' not in str(message.author.roles):
        if 'discord.gg' in message.content:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            print('had inv link')
        if '@everyone' in message.content:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            print('had everyone')
        if '@here' in message.content:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            print('had here')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'735893522032623646' while str(message.author.roles) is a list with `Role` objects, not `Role IDS`, so you need to check if it's in the list of Role IDS.

Also do `message.delete()` instead of `purge()` to delete the message, sometimes `purge` can delete other message too

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 735893522032623646 not in [i.id for i in message.author.roles]:
        if 'discord.gg' in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            print('had inv link')
        elif '@everyone' in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            print('had everyone')
        elif '@here' in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            print('had here')
    await client.process_commands(message)
```